# Is it possible to map the same mapping with different methods to two different controllers?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have two methods in my application that use the same request mapping with different (http) methods

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/method/{key}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void method1(<parameters>) throws IOException {
    // ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/method/{key}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void method2(<parameters>) throws IOException {
    // ...
}
```

This works perfectly as long as both methods are defined in the same Controller, however, because of a company framework I'm using, I **need for them to be in 2 different controllers**, and when I start my application, I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler 'MyController#0' to URL path [/method/{key}]: There is already handler of type [class OtherController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$54a955d] mapped.
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:390)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:362)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:82)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:58)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:72)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:109)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:393)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
>       ... 25 more

Is it at all possible to define them in different controllers or should I look at some (horrible) workaround (like renaming one of the URLs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work fine since Spring 3.1 (if new mapping implementation is enabled - it's enabled by default if use `<mvc:annotation-driven>` or `@EnableWebMvc` and don't declare any `HandlerMapping`s manually).

In older versions of Spring you have to put these methods into the same controller.

Comment: It'll be easier to modify the part that forces me to use 2 different controllers in our framework than to migrate everything that uses MVC to the newer versions. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful, it is annotation-driven, not driver. As it is only one letter, I am unable to edit it.